# Как добавить текст на картинку и сохранить эту картинку программно?

Tags: android, android-canvas

Хочу, что бы у пользователя была возможность добавить текст поверх картинки и потом возможность сохранить эту картинку. Как можно это реализовать в `Android`?

Comment: в каком размере нужно сохранить картинку? достаточно ли будет разрешения экрана или нужна картинка с большим разрешением?

Comment: Достаточно разрешения экрана, хотя вариант с большим разрешением тоже воможен.

Comment: https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-save-custom-layout-view-as-image-on-button-click-tutorial/

Comment: такой вариант устроит?

Comment: Выглядит неплохо, так в этом примере, сохраняется весь экран? или только выделенная часть (там где картинка, например) ?

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(layout); - передаете контейнер, который нужно сохранить
        saveChart(bitmap, layout.getMeasuredHeight(), layout.getMeasuredWidth());